# A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40

Tags: asp.net, .net-framework-version

I got the issue when my asp.net application on production is calling an api, a get request with query parameters only on an external api service. When I call the api from postman in production, .Net 4.7.2, and the event viewer shows the error "A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40".. It's working on my local machine and on staging machine when I call the api in Postman but not in production. Something might be blocking it in production.

When I lookup what is alert code 40 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/schannel-error-codes-for-tls-and-ssl-alerts), it says ssl3.

I tried enabling SSL3 on IISCrypto Tool to enable the protocol (though my application is calling the api on tls1.2) but still it doesn't work.

I even change the web request call to even use the HttpClient implementaion but still it works on local or staging but not on production.

I rule out the database as a cause because the simple api test using Postman would give predictable results. That is it works on local, staging but not on prod.

Can you provide inputs how to solve this?